# PHP Handling JSON... strange behavior

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to upload a file, and some data to my server, using Angular JS to make a POST request via AJAX, while my back end is Laravel 4 (not that it matters much here).

Now I successfully pass this data to my controller. I'm able to do the following:

```
$data = Input::all();
return $data;
```

I `console.log` the data out when the response is successful, and it produces:

```
Object {
    imageData: "{"title":"Some Title","owner":"Owner Name","source":"Source Name"}", 
    file: Object
}
```

Okay so this is what I want, but more specifcically I want the stuff inside of `imageData`.

```
    $data = Input::all();

    $imageData = $data['imageData'];

    return $imageData;
```

Okay so `console.log` that back:

```
Object {title: "Some Title", owner: "Owner Name", source: "Source Name"}
```

Great - but now lets grab the individual elements following that trend:

```
    $data = Input::all();

    $imageData = $data['imageData'];

    $title = $imageData['title'];

    return $title;
```

Nope: `500 (Internal Server Error)`. Same happens why I try to access it as an object (`$title = $imageData->title`.

So how am I supposed to grab the stuff inside of there?

Comment: Check your error logs to see what the 500 error really means.

Comment: could you print_r($imageData) just to see what it looks like from php

Comment: @JonathanKuhn  exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Illegal string offset 'title'' - not much else!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `$imageData` is a string. That string happens to contain JSON, but it's still a string none the less. You can tell by the fact that it starts and ends with a double quote `"`, which wouldn't be the case if it were actually JSON.

You problem is likely that you're passing JSON to something, which then converts the data to JSON.

Comment: Ah, yes I think you're right! And after some research a `json_decode( $data['imageData'], true)` seemed to do the job. Ta.